# Does making the handler (of the main UI fragment) publicly accessible have any complications?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I need to create a UI fragment that can be updated by many background threads. Does making the handler publicly accessible in the way shown below, have any complications? I have not come across anyone doing this and so I am a bit worried.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    WeakReference<MainFragment> mFrag;

    MyHandler(MainFragment aFragment) {
        mFrag = new WeakReference<MainFragment>(aFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        // Unpack message and handle specific UI updates
        // calling MainFragment's methods using the
        // weak reference 'mFrag'
    }
}

private static MyHandler mHandler;

// Create handler on resume
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mHandler = new MyHandler(this);
}

@Override
// Destroy handler on pause
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mHandler = null;
}

// When a background thread wants to update the main
// UI, it calls this method as
// MainFragment.getHandler().post(message)
public static Handler getHandler() {
    return mHandler;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a very clean design but it should not leak memory if that's your concern.

Comment: I can only think of having the handlers in a static hashmap of a say - HandlerProvider class, to make it cleaner. Is there a better way?

Comment: That in my opinion would be even worse. You should find a way to pass the reference to the handler directly to the threads and release it when the fragment is getting dismissed